# Pdf from web api service not opening

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2

Below is my code, actually it downloads pdf file but it might be corrupt or something wrong with it. Can you please help me with this?

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExportPDF()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response =
           Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No data to export.");
        MemoryStream _stream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            _stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("da adasdasd adasd"));
            //if file the dowload
            if (_stream.Length > 0)
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new StreamContent(_stream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _stream.Length;
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Responses.pdf";
            }
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(response); 
        }
    }
```

And Below is result:
[image]

Comment: the binary content of `da adasdasd adasd` doesn't seem to be a valid pdf.

Comment: @TZHX But when i change the entension to ".doc or .docx" it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All, I have used "SelectPDF" library and it is working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

You generate a text file in the MemoryStream.
If you change **"application/pdf" to "text/plain"** it should work.

If you really want to generate a PDF file in the MemoryStream, there are some libraries that can help you to do it like IronPdf, Aspose,...

Comment: Slim KTARI, Yes i also generated it with "SelectPdf" library but still the same issue.

Comment: if you replace _stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("da adasdasd adasd"));
by 
 _stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("PathToYourPdf\\download.pdf"));

your code will work